# How do I use variable within consul-template range construct?

Tags: consul-template

We have multiple environments for our apps, and I am trying to use generic consul template and an environment variable to create haproxy configurations for different environments.
 This is what I am trying to do:

{{$environment := "yellow" }}
....
balance leastconn {{range service "myservice-{{$env}}"}}
....

I cannot seem to find a way to use this variable within this range. Is there a way to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to define the variable and then use it in the range statement.

```
{{ $service_name := env "CONSUL_SERVICE_NAME" }}

{{range service $service_name }}
```